# How can I efficiently get a large amount of data from a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, web3js

I have a contract that will store a lot of data.  Offline solutions really don't apply to the problem I'm trying to solve, short of caching (but then I have a cache invalidation problem I'd have to solve too).

I only need to update small amounts of data at a time, so that fits easily under maxGas because of the "gas charge only on changing to non-zero value" feature of the EVM, but I need to be able to read a large amount of data at a time, and I'm having problems with that.

When I try to read a large amount via a solidity ABI, I get an out of gas error in the geth logfile (but nothing programmatically from web3.js call() which doesn't even take a gas argument), and I just get all zeros from web3.js despite the fact that I've modified a memory location.

Will `web3.eth.getStorageAt` work more efficiently or will it also run out of gas?  If this method works better than invoking the EVM, and I'm using fixed arrays, how do I find the address of the data?  Is there an alternative solution that minimizes overhead on the Ethereum node I'm talking to?

example code:

```
uint8 [10][10][100][100] public blocks;
// this quietly runs out of gas even in a call()
function getBlocks() returns (uint8[10][10][100][100]) {
        return blocks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls should not be rate limited. I think there was a bug in the RPC that for some reason assigned a default gas limit to calls. Could you try with this PR against develop? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2308

Comment: that's most likely it.  However invoking the EVM still seems inefficient.  Isn't there a way to locate the raw address of the fixed-size array?

Comment: I can't upgrade to Homestead for another 3 weeks, critical demo juncture...I'll post an update when I get there.

Comment: Take care, the Homestead chain **will** be immediately incompatible with the current Frontier chain. The moment the switch over happens, old clients on the main net will be left behind (already happened on the test net).